# Prove of basis for the topology defined on a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, compactness

Consider $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological space and define Open($X$) as the topological space where each point is the sets in $\mathcal{T}$ i.e. Open($X$) = $\mathcal{T}$. Define a topology on Open($X$) and I want to show that the basis of that topology is formed by the sets $\uparrow K=\{U \in\mathcal{T}|K \subseteq U\}$ where each $K$ is compact in $X$.

I know in this case, for each $A\in$Open($X$), if $A\in U$ for some $U$ in the topology on Open($X$), we need to find some compact space in $X$ such that $\uparrow K$ is contained in $U$, but I have no clue on this. Would anyone please give me some hints on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that all sets $\uparrow K$ form a base for *some* topology we have to check two conditions (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) or Munkres' textbook):

1. Their union is the whole space $\text{Open}(X)$.

This is trivial as $\uparrow \emptyset = \text{Open}(X)$ and $\emptyset$ is compact.

2. For every two basic $\uparrow K$ and $\uparrow K'$ and every $O \in \text{Open}(X)$ in $(\uparrow K) \cap (\uparrow K')$ we can find a basic $\uparrow K''$ such that $O \in \uparrow K'' \subseteq (\uparrow K) \cap (\uparrow K')$.

So we have $K \subseteq O$ and $K' \subseteq O$. Then $K \cup K'$ is compact (a finite union of compact sets in a space is still compact) and so $K''= K \cup K'$ is as required, as $K \cup K' \subseteq O$ etc.

So these sets indeed form the base for a unique topology on $\text{Open}(X)$, which consists of all union of subfamilies from that base.